# date formatting datefield in django

Tags: django, dateformatter, datefield

I want to have the given format "dd/mm/yyyy" overall the application, but momentally I have "mm/dd/yyyy".

Here's the code in ***models.py***

```
period_from = models.DateField(db_column="Period From", blank=True, null=True)
```

How to define it for all the datefields and in which file?

Comment: You can use the [**`DATE_FORMAT`** setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATE_FORMAT) to specify how to format a `date` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**`DATE_FORMAT`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATE_FORMAT) and [**`SHORT_DATE_FORMAT`** settings [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-SHORT_DATE_FORMAT) to specify how Django will format date objects.

Note that if you enable [**`USE_L10N`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-USE_L10N), then these settings will *not* have effect, and Django will format the date according to the *locale* of the user.

Comment: How is that supposed to be written in my code?

Comment: @EraKastrati:in the `settings.py` file.

Comment: but none of them is dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: @EraKastrati: you need to set the format, so `SHORT_DATE_FORMAT = 'd/m/Y'` see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-date) for the string format specifiers.

Comment: that file is named base.py in my app and I added SHORT_DATE_FORMAT = 'd/m/Y' but there are no changes, still the date in the period_from field is mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: @EraKastrati: but you specify this in the **`settings.py`** file.

Comment: but we named settings.py as base.py